# Swift UICollectionViewCell resize with content

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitextview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a problem with UICollectionViewCell and it is really hard for a newbie like me. I need your help.
I am working on a dictionary. I have a search bar, a collection view, some labels and a text view. But I can not resize neither collection view cell nor text view when showing search results.

View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class sozlukController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{
    @IBOutlet var wordSearchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet var collection: UICollectionView!
    var wordDataList = [String]()
    var meaningDataList = [String]()
    var dictionaryDataList = [String]()
    var yearDataList = [String]()

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar)  {
        wordDataList = []
        meaningDataList = []
        dictionaryDataList = []
        yearDataList = []
        var word = searchBar.text
        var parser:dictXMLParser = dictXMLParser()
        var searchResults:[dictXMLResponse]=parser.beginParsing(1, searchType: 1, searchWord: word)

        for result in searchResults {
            wordDataList.append(result.word)
            meaningDataList.append(result.meaning)
            dictionaryDataList.append(result.dictionary)
            yearDataList.append(result.year)
        }
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        searchBar.text=""
         collection.reloadData()

    }



    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return wordDataList.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell:meaningCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! meaningCollectionViewCell
        cell.wordLabel.text = wordDataList[indexPath.row]
        cell.meaningText.text = meaningDataList[indexPath.row]
        cell.dictionaryLabel.text = dictionaryDataList[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }


}
```

UICollectionViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class meaningCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell , UITextViewDelegate{
    @IBOutlet var wordLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var meaningText: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var dictionaryLabel: UILabel!

    override func  layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let fixedWidth = meaningText.frame.size.width
        let newSize = meaningText.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
        meaningText.frame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)

    }

}
```

When I wrote "gamze" in the search bar for the "first" time, I did not see the entire meaning because of text view height.

[Screenshot of first search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2kZm.png)

Surprisingly when I wrote the same word for a second search, text view height increased and it covered the following label. But again I could not see entire meaning because of UICollectionViewCell height.

[Screenshot of second search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL5UQ.png)

I set scrollable "false" and auto layout "on" through the interface builder.
Is there a way you know to show the meaning in the textview which does not cover any label and resize collection view cell according to its content

I am having trouble finding sources about swift. If you can help I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great solution on github. The trick is creating xib file for cell content

https://github.com/honghaoz/Dynamic-Collection-View-Cell-With-Auto-Layout-Demo